# will display port to HDMI support 4K?

Tags: graphics-card

forum newbie here. I have my HP Envy 12gb ram, with a AMD Radeon HD 7570 hooked to my new 4K Vizio M55 C2. Ive used this setup with my old HDTV for years, now with a new 4K tv, i now realize I'm not getting 4K signal from PC. I'm amazed at the picture quality while using pc & streaming video etc. My graphics card is capable of 3840x2400 using the display port. HDMI port is 1920x1200. Can I just buy a HDMI to DP converter plug to my PC? Or buy a DP cable with HDMI plug? Will signal remain 4K? The TV has 4 HDMI ports, 60hz & 30hz. I'm happy the way it is because it does a good job at upscaling but just wanted to see if it be better. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it depends on the quality of the adapter and if the hdmi port you are connecting to supports 4K - Thru experience, the bigger the adapter, the better the output. Some use an extra USB port for the 5v power.

Comment: yes the HDMI port is 4K in the 4K tv. 2 at 30hz & 2 at 60hz. I may have been a little confusing initially. The PC graphics card has both DP & HDMI out. The DP has max res of 3840x2400, so I currently use the HDMI port in display card to tv HDMI, which is 4K. can I put a DP adapter on the HDMI cable and plug it into the PC DP port and get 4K signal to the TV? sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

From your own words:

My graphics card is capable of 3840x2400 using the display port.
and
HDMI port is 1920x1200.

If you use the output from the HDMI port (at max 1920x1200) and convert it to DP then that DP connection will also be max 1920x1200.

---

The actual problem is not resolution thoughm it is bandwidth. Older HDMI versions simply do not have the bandwidth for 4k @ 60Hz. If you have HDMI 2.0 on both card and monitor then everything will work fine,, if you have HDMI 1.0 (1.1, 1.2,..) then the HDMI port is limited. You cannot push enough information per second out of it to get 4k @ 60Hz.  If ytou are lucky you can get 4K at 30Hz which might work but often results in a laggy mouse.

To properly use 4k use either DP (both on the output and on the monitor) or use a modern HDMI version.

Comment: I'm sorry, where I said the DP max res is 3840x2400 & HDMI max res is 1920x1200, I meant both ports are on my PC display card. I use the HDMI port currently out to the 4K tv. Can I use the current HDMI cable with a DP adapter on the PC side?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I believe I have the info I need. I'll give it a shot. Just ordered this from Amazon because no one carries what I need locally. [https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-DisplayPort-HDTV-Supporting/dp/B01672IR6I/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1479586435&sr=1-1&keywords=display+port+to+hdmi+cable+4k](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01672IR6I)

Thanks again.